# android in app billing package name change

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to run the in app billing sample code.  I try to change the package name from com.example.dungeons to com.mydomain.dungeons.  I change the package name by right clicking on the project name, then Android Tools ==> Rename Application Package.  After I enter the new package name, I get a bunch of warnings because it adds an import to every class file like so:

```
import com.mydomain.dungeons.R;
```

What does this line mean?  Also, I notice the package declaration for each class is still:

```
package com.example.dungeons
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just told the *Android tools* that your package changed. This caused the ADT to re-generate the `R` class with the new package declaration and changed the package in `AndroidManifest.xml`; it also updated all references to the `R` class in your code for you.

You still have to actually rename the package declarations in your *code*, preferably by using an Eclipse refactoring (right click on the package, etc.).

Comment: Eclipse automatically adds the import for R. If your files are in the root package, these imports are not necessary. Delete them if you want.

Answer (score 0):

eclipse import your ID of elements. 
 and you have standard android elements(layout, Widgets etc)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html

eclipse create R file, when you you clean project (project>clean)